# PHP Regex: CSS Relative to Absolute

Tags: php, css, regex, url, relative-path

I have a problem with a difficult regex. I have this expression to detect absolute urls (http and https

```
/(url {0,}\(( {0,}'| {0,}"|))(?!http|data\:).*?\)/im
```

What I want to do basically is with `preg_replace` to prepend the url with a path `$path` defined in my script. Basically this regex results in two capture groups:

```
group 1: (url {0,}\(( {0,}'| {0,}"|))(?!http).*?\)

group 2: ( {0,}'| {0,}"|)
```

How can I match all the way until the uri starts and then prepend it with `$path`? I can't seem to get the capturing groups right.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you are doing?  Are you trying to replace all the paths in a single CSS file? Multiple CSS files?  Are there multiple paths that need to be replaced?  If it is just for one file doing a simple find and replace in a text editor may prove to be the fastest solution.

Comment: Basically I have a wordpress plugin which loads all loaded css files. It combines them and writes them to a file in a different location. However, relative resource need to be converted to absolute ones in order for them to be loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$re = '/\b url \s*+ \( \s*+ (?| " ([^"]*+) " | \' ([^\']*+) \' | (\S*+) ) \s*+ \) /ix';

$str = preg_replace_callback($re, function ($match) {
    $url = $match[1];
    // do some check on the url
    if(whatever)
        return $match[0]; // return without change

    // do whatever you want with the URL
    // return new url
    return "url(\"$url\")";
}, $str);
```